# Preveting DNS Leaks using gnupg over TOR while allowing key-fetching via DNS

Tags: gnupg, tor

Using DANE to associate OpenPGP public keys with email addresses becomes more and more popular. There are different methods implemented in GnuPG and used like pka and cert. IETF just released a new draft proposing a new [OPENPGPKEY DNS Resource Record](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/draft-ietf-dane-openpgpkey/).

Public key lookups raised privacy issues since they could leak informations about who someone is communicating with. Torify GnuPG was one way to address these issues. There are three widely used methods for that:

1. Using `torsocks`:

   `torsocks gpg --search test@examples.com`
2. Using `http-proxy` option in `keyserver-options` of GnuPG:

   `gpg --keyserver-options http-proxy=socks5h://127.0.0.1:9050`
3. Using one of the above together with a keyserver available as Tor Hidden Service.

Since GnuPG lacks native support of socks proxy DNS Leaks are a major problem. It becomes even more dramatic when a DNS leak also contains email address of people you are communicating with. None of the approaches mentioned above allows fetching keys from DNS while preventing DNS leaks:

1. Using `torsocks` doesn't leak information in DNS, but therefore blocks DNS key fetch.
2. Using `http-proxy` option in `keyserver-options` of GnuPG leaks email addresses in DNS.
3. Since keyserver is not used it doesn't matter if it's a tor hidden service or not.

Also `tor-resolve` does only support DNS A-records and therefore can't be used to retrieve OpenPGP key information stored in DNS as `TXT` (pka), `TYPE37` (cert) or `OPENPGPKEY` (IETF draf) records.

Is there any way to torify GnuPG without DNS leak issues and without blocking DANE support?

Comment: Tor has an option to receive DNS requests `DNSPort` and resolve them over Tor.  So you can set your DNS servers to the local IP that your Tor daemon is listening on.  Read more here: https://trac.torproject.org/projects/tor/wiki/doc/TransparentProxy

Comment: I don't want tor to resolve all DNS request since this would slow down normal work to much. Also there might be problems since TOR only resolves DNS queries for A-records; neither MX nor NS queries are supported. TOR should only be used to resolve DNS queries from GnuPG.